# Using the online code editor, changing the code doesn't update the bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

We have a bot on Azure. We normally have continuous deployment deploy the code and it works great. But for now, I want to edit the code for the bot using the online code editor. When I make changes and restart the server, it restarts in almost a second. I'm confident it didn't run some build steps. But then when I test the bot, I don't see the changes in my bot.

Is there some command I have to run after I change the code in order to see the changes in my bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this bot is node, it should update automatically. If the bot is C#, you're going to have to run Build.cmd for it to build correctly. Open the console (second icon up from bottom, hightlighted white in this image)

[image: console icon highlighted]

Then type 'build.cmd' into the console.

[image: build.cmd command typed into console]

if it's successful, it will show.

[image: successful build command run]